# Write a function that accepts a list of numbers and a single number as parameters. The function should print all the numbers less than the number

Tags: python, function, parameters

[click here to view my code and question please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7nmK.png)

Beginner Python programmer learning to code so please help by click the first link.

I might as well  paste the code here for you to save you time.

```
def printValues(val1, lst=[]):
    for val1 in lst:
        if lst < val1:
            print(lst)
```

Cant seem to make the code work as I cant figure out how to accept a list of numbers and a single parameter. Try my best to figure out how to print all the numbers less than the number. See question for clarification. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating in the wrong way.Also, you are trying to compare a number with list. Check the below code

```
In [4]: val1= 5

In [5]: list2 = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9]
In [7]: def printValues(val1, lst=[]):
   ...:     for val in lst:
   ...:         if val < val1:
   ...:             print(val)
   ...:

In [8]: printValues(val1,list2)
1
2
3
```